# Canon MG4150 wireless Printer won't add to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: printing, canon

Running Ubuntu 17.10 and at first the printer added without much problems. I have since reinstalled Ubuntu due to some other problem and now it suddently won't add the printer, I get the error "Failed to add new printer".

Using system-config-printer in the terminal leads to the following:

```
(system-config-printer.py:6755): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_store_insert_after: assertion 'G_NODE (sibling->user_data)->parent == G_NODE (parent->user_data)' failed

(system-config-printer.py:6755): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_store_set_value: assertion 'VALID_ITER (iter, tree_store)' failed

(system-config-printer.py:6755): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_store_set_value: assertion 'VALID_ITER (iter, tree_store)' failed
Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 4227, in getNPPPD
ppd = cups.PPD(f)
RuntimeError: ppdOpenFile failed
```

I have tried other suggestions like installing ppa:inameiname, this also didn't work due to other problems (unauthenticated packages...)

Comment: you could try the Canon drivers from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100395002.html and if you download and save, the commands to install are `cd Downloads`  `tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg4100series-3.60-1-deb.tar.gz`  `cd cnijfilter-mg4100series-3.60-1-deb` and `sudo ./install.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your printer via cups' webinterface:

http://localhost:631

Also you could check your systems python version, possibly several versions are installed.

Comment: Indeed, I installed Anaconda recently, executing pythong --version gives 3.6.4, but in the /usr/lib folder there are the following directories:
python2.7/ python3/   python3.6/ python3.7/ 
Does that make a difference?

Comment: Is there an option in your Bios for that touchpad maybe, where you can switch from "advanced" to "basic" or similar ?

Comment: I didn't find anything like it. I am running a Lenovo Thinkpad T420. What would that have to do with the printer?

Comment: Update: it seems that no printer at all can be added. I am now at work and the printers can all be found on the network but none of them can be added!

Comment: I tried installing from the web interface and got the error "Unable to copy PPD file"

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you ever solve it?